# frustrated trying to complete trail and getting this error message: Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: JWTBearerFlow at line 20 column 31

Tags: apex, trailhead, jwt

```
public class VisionController {
    // You can upload the `einstein_platform.pem` into your Salesforce org as `File` sObject and read it as below
    public String getAccessToken() {
        // Ignore the File upload part and "jwt.pkcs" if you used a Salesforce certificate to sign up 
        // for an Einstein Platform account
        ContentVersion base64Content = [SELECT Title, VersionData FROM ContentVersion where Title='einstein_platform' OR  Title='predictive_services' ORDER BY Title LIMIT 1];
        String keyContents = base64Content.VersionData.tostring();
        keyContents = keyContents.replace('-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '');
        keyContents = keyContents.replace('-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----', '');
        keyContents = keyContents.replace('\n', '');

        // Get a new token
        JWT jwt = new JWT('RS256');
        // jwt.cert = 'JWTCert'; // Uncomment this if you used a Salesforce certificate to sign up for an Einstein Platform account
        jwt.pkcs8 = keyContents; // Comment this if you are using jwt.cert
        jwt.iss = 'developer.force.com';
        jwt.sub = 'johnfpopesr@yahoo.com';
        jwt.aud = 'https://api.metamind.io/v1/oauth2/token';
        jwt.exp = '3600';
        String access_token = JWTBearerFlow.getAccessToken('https://api.metamind.io/v1/oauth2/token', jwt);
        return access_token;    
    }

    public List<Vision.Prediction> getCallVisionUrl() {
        // Get a new token
        String access_token = getAccessToken();

        // Make a prediction using URL to a file
        return Vision.predictUrl('http://metamind.io/images/generalimage.jpg',access_token,'GeneralImageClassifier');
    }

    public List<Vision.Prediction> getCallVisionContent() {
        // Get a new token
        String access_token = getAccessToken();

        // Make a prediction for an image stored in Salesforce
        // by passing the file as blob which is then converted to base64 string
        ContentVersion content = [SELECT Title,VersionData FROM ContentVersion where Id = '06841000000LkfCAAS' LIMIT 1];
        return Vision.predictBlob(content.VersionData, access_token, 'GeneralImageClassifier');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

John - It seems you have not created JWTBearerFlow class in your org.

Please get it from here: https://github.com/salesforceidentity/jwt/blob/master/JWTBearer.apex

This should fix your issue.